# Как прервать выполение программы при выполнении условия?

Tags: c++, clion

Как при выполнении вот этого завершить программу, а иначе продолжить проверку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Смысла тут нету я просто изменил значения.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

TTF:
string name, name_1="LL", name_2="No";
    cout << "What's your name?\n";

getline(cin, name);

 if (name==name_1)
    cout << "Welcome to the tavern!\n " << name;
 else if (name==name_2)
     cout << "Yes\n";
 else
    cout<<"Good \n";

goto TTF;
```

Comment: используй оператор `return` там, где нужен выход

Comment: [man assert](https://linux.die.net/man/3/assert), [man exit](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exit), [man abort](https://linux.die.net/man/3/abort)

Comment: @Majestio Я отредактировал пост посмтори пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать ключевое слово `return`:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 

int main() { 
TTF: string name, name_1="LL", name_2="No"; 
cout << "What's your name?\n";
getline(cin, name); 
if (name==name_1) 
    cout << "Welcome to the tavern!\n " << name; 
else if (name==name_2) 
    return 0; # выход из программы
else 
    cout<<"Good \n"; 
goto TTF;
```